# Weirdness when data POST to PHP script

Tags: php, android, mysql, post, httpclient

I am using the following code to post data from an android app to a PHP script:

```
public class Upload extends Activity implements OnClickListener {
EditText joke;
Button upload = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bUpload);
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.upload);
    upload.setOnClickListener(this);
}
public void onClick(View v) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    switch (v.getId()) {
    case R.id.bUpload:
        uploadJoke();
        break;
    }

}
private void uploadJoke() {
    // Create a new HttpClient and Post Header
    HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://xxxx/telejoke.php");

    try {
        // Add your data
        List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(2);
        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("username", "test"));
        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("joke", joke.getText().toString()));
        httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));

        // Execute HTTP Post Request
        HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);

    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
    } catch (IOException e) {
    }
}
```

This code sends data to a PHP script, which then sends it on to an SQL database. This data shows up in the SQL database, but if I try something like `echo $username` it doesn't show the username when I go to http://xxxx/telejoke.php.

PHP script:

```
<?php
  include 'DBConnect.php';
  include 'JokeValidate.php';

  $username = $_POST['username'];
  $joke = $_POST['joke'];
  $dbname = 'Telejoke';
  mysql_select_db($dbname);

  echo $username. " " . $joke;

  if (validate()){
    $query = "INSERT INTO jokes (username, joke) VALUES ('$username','$joke')";
    mysql_query($query) or die('Error, insert query failed');
  }
  mysql_close($conn);
?>
```

Please help. I want to do things to the posted data with PHP besides just send it on to database.

Comment: If the data is making it to the database fine, then we need to see telejoke.php since there is nothing wrong with the java code.

Comment: Why not post your php code? This client code isn't going to help much with an issue in your server code

Comment: Button click is definitley workging. I can see the data in my database after upload. EditText joke is used in `nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("joke", joke.getText().toString()));
`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess register_globals is off (which is fine)!!!

You have to address username via $_POST['username'] (of course in telepost.php).

OKAY (after you posted your php-script I think I got it).
You said "after going to http://xxx/telejoke.php i cannot see my username, but the data is uploaded correctly".

--> Yeah, that behaviour is correct.
You do not pass any POST parameters to your php script, so $_POST['username'] is empty.

--> But if you call the script via your application you pass the required POST paramters (username, joke, etc) to your script. So it can write your data correctly in your database.

In addition you should optimize your SQL/script to prevent SQL injection.
A bad user may cause damage to your website (e.g. deleting all jokes, etc...)

Comment: Well when I call the script from my app, and then go to http://xxx/telejoke.php, shouldn't it echo the username of the last posted joke? If this is the case, it is not happening. Ill worry about user injection later, but thanks for the heads up.

Comment: No, because it is a new request (by default http is state less -> no information is stored) and therefore you have to pass the request parameter to your script, otherwise nothing will happen. But you can create a page - lets say listjokes.php - where you see all jokes stored in database.